# Mod in C#: It returns a wrong value

Tags: c#, math, encryption, rsa

Ok, here's my code:

```
       int a, b, c, d;
        double v1, v2, v3, vf, val;

        a = 110;
        b = 13;
        c = 437;
        d = 61;

        v1 = Convert.ToDouble(a);
        v2 = Convert.ToDouble(b);
        v3 = Convert.ToDouble(d);

        val = Math.Pow(v1, v2);
        val = val % c;

        Console.WriteLine("O valor do primeiro MOD é: {0}", val);

        vf = Math.Pow(val, v3);
        vf = vf % c;

        Console.WriteLine("O valor final é: {0}", vf);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Here's the thing, if i do that using the calculator i'll get these results:

**110**^**13** = **345227121439310000000000000**
**345227121439310000000000000** % **437** = **48**
**48**^**61** = **3,5951372914138399900210185557119e+102**
**3,5951372914138399900210185557119e+102** % **437** = **110**

But, using my code i get these results:

(http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1309/7l42tc.jpg)

For those who can't see the image, the results are:

val = 337
vf = 6

Comment: you need to use a big number library for such big numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work using doubles is because the double data type does not have sufficient precision. Large numbers such as `110^13` are not representable exactly as a double - they lose quite a lot of significant digits.

The solution is to calculate it using a type that can represent very large integers.

Here's how you can do it using `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(110);
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(13);
BigInteger c = new BigInteger(437);

BigInteger val = BigInteger.ModPow(a, b, c);
```

Note how there's a specific method, `ModPow()`, that combines raising to a power and modulus.

Also note that you can make use of an implicit constructor which converts an `int` to a `BigInteger`, which simplifies the above code to:

```
BigInteger val = BigInteger.ModPow(110, 13, 437);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful but i'm still stuck. I was using the 2008 version now i'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. 

I started a new project using NET Framework 4.0 as target and added the System.Numerics reference (Solution Explorer> Right Click> Add Reference> .NET> System.Numerics) but i get the error "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'BigInteger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Thank you for you support. After a more detailed observation i found that i missed the line "using System.Numerics;".

Comment: @Matthew Your answer does not explain anything. It does not explain why the code in the question does not work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added more explanation. I was really expecting yours to be marked as the answer, and I was just adding some code to help the OP.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks. I guess asker appreciated having the code fleshed out for them.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `110^13` nor `48^61` are exactly representable using 64 bit double precision. The data type does not have sufficient precision to represent these values exactly. Because you cannot represent your operands exactly, you are actually performing different arithmetic from that which you intend to perform. Once you've been unable to represent the original operands, there is no hope of recovery.

You need to use a type with sufficient precision. For instance, [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Double has far from enough precision for your case. Double is [precise to 16 digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Your values have 26 and 102 digits respectively. The digits that cannot be represented are simply lost, resulting in lost of precision.

You should be using some kind of bigint library:

- [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) (from .NET 4.0)
- [BigInteger class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class)